# I would like to know the "criteria" when I got downvoted with no explanation

Tags: discussion

When I myself downvote, I add the reason for downvotes.

Whereas, sometimes or often, I get downvotes with no reason attached.

If the moderators would like this site to be more positive, would you better suggest for the users to comment when downvoting?

Then the answerer with the mistake can **improve himself/herself**.

Comment: By the way, there are so many issues for each individuals, I think whenever I come up, I try to use the "source-oriented" method as much as I can. Thank you.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/731/1478

Comment: Moderators can't make people comment when they downvote, although I agree that it's useful for them to do so.

Comment: Withoud doubt. I am asking for these who downvotes with no reason attached.